# Check the index of a number in a list in a dictionary

Tags: python

i have this dictionary in witch each key contains a list of two numbers i want to access a number from the list by its index.

example:

```
list1 = {'pos2': (80, 14), 'pos3': (120, 14), 'pos5': (200, 14), 'pos6': (240, 14)}
```

I have tried this solution and it kept giving me an key error

```
list1 = {'pos2': (80, 14), 'pos3': (120, 14), 'pos5': (200, 14), 'pos6': (240, 14)}

print(list1["pos2"[0]])
```

Output

```
    print(posind['pos2'[0]])
KeyError: 'p'
```

If you know any solution or can help me in any way please let me know.

Comment: You're indexing the key there, i.e. the string, and so the key to lookup is the indexed string, `p`. You need to index the result from the lookup  `list1["pos2"][0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking the order of you brackets.
you have

```
print(list1["pos2"[0]])
```

while it should be something along the lines of

```
print(list1["pos2"][0]) # changed bracket position
```